# Php pdo result of JOIN query

Tags: php, sql, join, object, pdo

### My problem is

I try to do a simple JOIN between two tables, that both have the id field. My result is an stdClass object, as I use PDO. Does anyone know how can I make a difference between the id of the first table and the id of the second table?

### Code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products AS p 
        products_categories AS c 
        WHERE c.id = p.category";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$products = array();

while($product = $stmt->fetchObject())
    $products[] = $product;

return $products;
```

If I try to use $products->id, it will show me the id of the *category* table. If it was an array, I could use $products['p.id'] , I need an alternative to this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give a column alias to the `id` column from one table or the other to make the column names distinct.

This means you can't use "`SELECT *`", you have to spell out *all* the column names you want to fetch from that table.  At least you can still query for `category.*` if you want all those columns without aliasing.

By the way, this sort of problem is a good reason to avoid using a generic name like "`id`" for your primary key in every table.  Instead use a more descriptive names like `product_id` and `category_id`.  Then you won't have the problem of conflicting column names.

Comment: I've researched this on the mysql website, but I didn't liked it because my products table has lots of columns. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: So fetch `p.*` and alias the `id` column from the other table.

Comment: This 
bc. SELECT p.*, c.id AS category_id, c.name
FROM products AS p, products_categories as c
WHERE c.id = p.category

Worked . Thanks.

I found this : http://us2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php . So when I use JOINS i can return it as an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT c.car_id, c.car_name, d.dealers_name,m.maker_name
FROM car_details AS c, dealer_details AS d,maker_details AS m
WHERE c.dealer_id=d.dealer_id AND c.maker_id=m.maker_id");

$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
select 
    clientes.nombre AS cn, 
    proyectos.nombre AS pn 
FROM 
    proyectos 
        LEFT JOIN clientes 
            ON proyectos.clienteId = clientes.id
```

This worked with PDO using `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`