# Master-Detail using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, master-detail

I'm stuck trying to create a result page that lists details based on a series of masters.

Here's a sample problem...

Three tables such as those shown below:

```
Book (id, title)
Author (id, name)
BookAuthors (bookID, authorID)
```

I wish to generate a list similar to this:

```
Book Title 1
  Author 1
  Author 2
Book Title 2
  Author 3
Book Title 3
  Author 1
  Author 4
```

and so on.

I wish to use PHP PDO to achieve this.

[Updated with more detail]

The problem I have is more about how to go about traversing the results from the PDO when nesting prepared statements is not possible...

I was hoping to nest a query within a query and use the results from the 1st query [I've extended the query to include a filter on the book titles, but this may be blank thus returning the whole set]:

```
select id as idBook,title from book where title like %:title%
```

to then create the list of authors for each book

```
select name from author, bookauthors 
  where bookauthor.authorid = author.id 
    AND bookauthor.bookid = :idBook:
```

Where :idBook: is the next book id from the result set from the 1st query.

As the number of books retrieved in the 1st query may be large, I was hoping not to use fetchall if possible...

Anyone got pointers / sample solution code for this?

many thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no sample code but I send you love and happiness Ady! You're looking for a `join`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php pdo result of JOIN query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380691/php-pdo-result-of-join-query)

Comment: @hakre I understand that I will be using Joins, the problem I have is traversing the results. I was hoping to nest a query within a query and use the results from the 1st query (select id as idBook,title from book) to then create the list of authors for each book (select name from author, bookauthors where bookauthor.authorid = author.id AND bookauthor.bookid = :idBook:).

Comment: Read up on lastInsertId() http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: Mike S - I'm not needing the lastinsertid for that problem. I was not adding new records, but was doing a master-detail-subdetail display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of multiple queries I'd rather store some state in a php variable. In this case all you need to know is: has the book "changed", i.e. must the script print the title?

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
foo($pdo);  // add test data

$r = $pdo->query('
  SELECT
    l.bookID, b.title, a.name
  FROM
    BookAuthor as l
  JOIN
    Author as a
  ON
    a.id=l.authorID 
  JOIN
    Book as b
  ON
    b.id=l.bookID
  ORDER BY
    l.bookID,
    l.authorID
');
$currentBook = null;
foreach($r as $row) {
  if ( $currentBook!=$row['bookID'] ) {
    echo $row['title'], "\n";
    $currentBook=$row['bookID'];
  }
  echo '  ', $row['name'], "\n";
}

function foo($pdo) {
  $pdo->exec('create temporary table Book (id int auto_increment, title varchar(48), primary key(id))');
  $pdo->exec('create temporary table Author (id int auto_increment, name varchar(48), primary key(id))');
  $pdo->exec('create temporary table BookAuthor (bookID int, authorID int)');

  $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO Author (id,name) VALUES (1,'Author1'),(2,'Author2'),(3,'Author3'),(4,'Author4')");
  $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO Book (id,title) VALUES (1,'Book Title 1'),(2,'Book Title 2'),(3,'Book Title 3')");
  $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO BookAuthor (bookID,authorID) VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,4)");
}
```

Comment: That was my next thought, but wanted to avoid it if possible... I've been playing with a fetchall() idea, but will also implement your ideas as well and compare. Thankyou